# how to verify a contract using truffle-plugin-verify

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I'm trying to verify a simple contract. The contract is already deployed on the Ropsten network.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Tress is ERC20, AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");

    constructor() public ERC20("TRESS", "TRS") {
        // Grant the contract deployer the default admin role: it will be able
        // to grant and revoke any roles
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not a minter");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) public {
        require(hasRole(BURNER_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not a burner");
        _burn(from, amount);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. It throws me the following error.
[image]

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

By looking on the errors, there seems to be a file system problem as the command is not seeing the contract `Tress.sol`.(Can you give more details?).

Errors during verifying, can also occur if you delete the **build** directory after your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this error later. This was a bug in truffle-plugin-verify that has since been fixed in [v0.5.3](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify/releases/tag/v0.5.3).